# how to make links load or refresh within a webview in android?

Tags: android

when i load a url in a webview. it loads perfectly.

but i touch anything in that webview its redirected to the browser by default.

how to set that link will load in the same webview itself.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a `WebViewClient`, overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to tell Android what you want to do on link clicks. Attach that `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` via `setWebViewClient()`.